# Collapse Bootstrap 3 Nav Using Regular CSS (not LESS or SASS)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to figure out how to use a media query to collapse the bootstrap 3 collapsible nav without using LESS. I haven't made it around to using LESS with bootstrap yet, I'm just using regular CSS. It seems that nothing I do will trigger the navbar to collapse. I'm trying to collapse it at anything smaller than 950px across.

Any ideas? I can't find any posts that refer to regular CSS doing what I need.

Comment: Can you share what you've already tried? Why not add just add Bootstrap's own `collapse` class to the element?

Comment: It of course has the collapse class on the element, and it collapses at the default breakpoint in bootstrap 3. I'm wanting to make that default breakpoint much wider. I believe it collapses around the 700px width. I want it to collapse at 950px.

Comment: Then just modify the media query inside `bootstrap.css`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CSS to change the breakpoint of the navbar..

```
@media (max-width: 950px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Working demo: http://bootply.com/105174